# sending one http request every 30 seconds

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I'm trying to send one http request every 30 seconds. But, it sends every second.

I'm confused using ramp-up period from thread group. and constant timer throughput.

which one I should use to achieve this test case?

Comment: Add what have you tried so far and where you got an error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) as a child of your request
2. Configure it like:

   - Target Throughput: `2` (2 samples per minute)
   - Calculate Throughput Based On: `all active threads in current thread group`

     [image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer Confit]
3. That's it, now your request should fire each 30 seconds

   [image: JMeter Constant Throughput Timer in Action]

---

Be aware that Constant Throughput Timer is accurate enough on **minute** level so it can start pausing the threads only after 1 minute. If you're using > 1 virtual user and uncertain regarding ramp-up settings consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) which is more precise out of the box. You can install Throughput Shaping Timer using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Comment: what's the corelation between this throughput timer and ramp-up period from thread group? can you explain me a bit how they both work together?

Comment: I also want to run n concurrent users per second, but still fail :(